# Check whether the series is conditional converges or absolutely converges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-n}{n+1}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check whether  the series is conditional converges or absolutely converges$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-n}{n+1}\right)^n$

My try:By using root test ,I got no conclusion .Kindly help.

Comment: Note that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<e\implies $ the general terms of the series do not approach $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Do you recognize $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$?

Comment: yes it is equal to $e$

Comment: So, what is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left|\big(\frac{-n}{n+1}\big)^n\right|$?

Comment: but how this will help?

Comment: I think $\frac1e$

Comment: Precisely. So, does the series converge?

Comment: no...series does not converges